# I got Exception: Unexpected status code "429" from ('translate.google.com',) and <Response [200]>

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to translate a column called `Full plain text` from a dataframe. I access this DataFrame from Google Cloud Platform Client. I have read that the max characters you can translate is 10k but when I run I always had an error. Then I made a threshold of 5k (which is the limit of the online translator you find if you google "google translator".

```
´´´
column_translation = "Full plain text no sig"
tr = Data.loc[:, [column_translation]]

# Make a threshold to divide the text
threshold = 5000

tr.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
l = []
for i in range(len(tr)):
    if len(tr.loc[i,column_translation]) < threshold:
        l.append(TR(text=tr.loc[i,column_translation], language="spanish"))
        print(f"{i+1} out of {len(tr)}")
´´´
```

I just reset the index of my data frame, which only has the `Full main text`, so I can use loc[] to get the value and `TR()` is the function that translates. When I first run it, I have more or less 9749 samples to translate but when I get to the 2000ish samples I get this error:

> Exception: Unexpected status code "429" from ('translate.google.com',) and <Response [200]>

Which I totally get is 429 error but what I do not understand is that I got a 200 response with `request.get()`. I wanted to make sure about it and I tried `(iwr -uri http://translate.google.com).StatusCode` at PowerShell (Win10) but I got a 200 !! I do not understand !! Also I wanted to get how much time I should wait for the next request but don't know where to look at; I have checked `(iwr -uri http://translate.google.com).Headers` but no rateLimit in there...

Comment: You exceeded their quota of free requests.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the checking you did, you checked `http://translate.google.com` which is **NOT** the [Google Cloud Translate API endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate). If you are using `http://translate.google.com` in your code and you are using it to translate a bulk of data, there is a high possibility that your IP is blocked because this is not the official Google Translate API.

You should be using `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2` endpoint in your code (which is the official Google Translate API). See the [Translate API guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart) on how to use Google Translate API. You can then check your usage in [Google Cloud Platform Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_project_quotas).

> To view quota usage and limits for all resources in your project:
>
> 1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Quotas page.
>
>    - The list includes one line item for each type of quota available in
>      each service.
> 2. Sort and filter the results to focus on the information you need:
>
>    - To view a specific property, click Filter table. Type in "Cloud Translation API" to view quotas for Cloud Translation API
>    - By default, the list is sortedto show your most used quota first (in terms of peak usage over the last seven days), which helps you see limits that are at risk of being exceeded. To view the least used first, toggle the Quota status arrow.
>    - To learn more about your Current Usage for a particular quota, in the Details column, click All Quotas.

Also the recommended maximum characters per request is 5K for basic translation and 30K for advanced translation. See [Translation quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content) for a detailed take on this.

Comment: Cool, but I still have more questions... =(

Comment: @ÁlvaroRomeroMato Feel free to create separate questions until you have a full understanding of thing that you are stuck with :)